# Javascript form submits twice

Tags: javascript, java, html, servlets, fetch

I have a login form which works with `Firebase auth` and connects to a `servlet`. The issue is it get submitted twice. Please check the below.

**javascript code**

```
function toggleSignIn() 
{
    if (firebase.auth().currentUser) 
    {
                    // [START signout]
                    //window.location.href = 'LoadSellPendingApprovals'
                    alert('existing user');
                    firebase.auth().signOut();
                    // [END signout]
                } else {
                    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
                    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
                    if (email.length < 4) {
                        alert('Please enter an email address.');
                        return;
                    }

                    if (password.length < 4) {
                        alert('Please enter a password.');
                        return;
                    }

                    // Sign in with email and pass.
                    // [START authwithemail]
                    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(firebaseUser) 
                    {
                        var email = firebase.auth().currentUser.email;
                        //alert(email);
                        // console.log(email) contains email
                        const options = {
                            method: 'POST',
                            //url: 'LoginValidator',
                            headers: {
                                // set appropriate headers, assuming json here
                                //"Content-Type": "application/json",
                                 "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                            },
                            // form body, assuming json
                            //body: JSON.stringify(email)
                             body: `email=${email}`
                        }
                        alert(email);
                         url = 'LoginValidator'
                        fetch(url, options)
                            .then(response => response.json())
                            .then(data => console.log(data))
      .                     catch(e => console.error(e))
                            window.location.href = 'LoginValidator'
                    })

                    .catch(function(error) 
                    {
                        // Handle Errors here.
                        var errorCode = error.code;
                        var errorMessage = error.message;
                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
                        if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') 
                        {
                            alert('Wrong password.');
                        } else {
                            alert(errorMessage);
                        }
                        console.log(error);
                        document.getElementById('quickstart-sign-in').disabled = false;
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    });
                //alert('hi');
                // [END authwithemail]
                }
                document.getElementById('quickstart-sign-in').disabled = true;

            }
```

My HTML form

```
<form id="login-form" class="form" action="" method="post">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control login-input" placeholder="username">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control login-input" type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password">
                                    <i id="open" class="fa fa-eye fa-2x"></i>
                                    <i id="closed" class="fa fa-eye-slash fa-2x"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="submit" id="quickstart-sign-in" name="quickstart-sign-in" class="form-control btn btn-info btn-md login-bt" value="Login" onclick="toggleSignIn()">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group text-center forgot">
                                    <a href="#">Forgot username</a> / <a href="#">password?</a>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

Below is my servlet (where the form is submitted to) in case you are interested

```
public class LoginValidator extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        System.out.println("Printing email: "+email);

        try {

            System.out.println("inside try");

            User user = new User();
            UserRight userRight = new UserRight();

            GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
            gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateTypeDeserializer());
            Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BaseURLs.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();

            //Get user
            RestEndPointsInterface endPoint = retrofit.create(RestEndPointsInterface.class);
            Call<User> call = endPoint.getUserByEmail(email);
            user = call.execute().body();

            System.out.println(user.getName());

            //Get user rights
            Call<UserRight> userRightCall = endPoint.getUserRightByID(user.getUserRights().getIduserRight());
            userRight = userRightCall.execute().body();

            System.out.println(userRight.getUserRight());

            if(userRight.getUserRight().equals("admin"))
            {
                RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("LoadSellPendingApprovals");
                requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
            }
            else
            {
                RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
                requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

In my IDE console the output is as follows (the output is printed by the `servlet`)

```
Printing email: email@example.com
inside try
Printing email: null
inside try
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path parameter "email" value must not be null.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is the culprit:

```
window.location.href = 'LoginValidator'
```

It appears in this code block:

```
fetch(url, options)
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(data => console.log(data))
   .catch(e => console.error(e))
   window.location.href = 'LoginValidator' // <= HERE
```

The indenting makes it look like it would be part of the `catch` block, but regardless of what happens in the rest of your function, this will get executed and send an additional GET request to your servlet.

And since your servlet doesn't distinguish between GET and POST requests (everything is redirected to `processRequest()`), you're seeing the output you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks, yes, now that issue is sorted. However now there is a new problem. eventhugh the request get sent to the `servlet`, the `servlet` now fails to resend the request to UI

Comment: I think the servlet correctly forwards your request, but since that is done in the scope of an AJAX request, it will not redirect your page (which seems to be what you're expecting).

Comment: what I need is, ldo the authentication with `firebase` ad send the request to Servlet so it can send it to a `jsp`. The `RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/mypage.jsp");` code in servlet simply do not work.

Comment: It does work, but you will see no result in your browser, because the request forwarding is done in response to an AJAX request, not a regular browser request.

Comment: How can I fix that?

Comment: Instead of doing a request forward, send back a string or a small piece of JSON containing the URL or path to forward to. When you receive that as a response to your AJAX request, call `window.location.href = url` or something similar.

Comment: Sorry but several attempts failed. I made another question, please try to help if you can - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55702527/requestdispatcher-forward-not-forwarding-when-servlet-called-via-ajax-post