# RequestDispatcher.forward() not forwarding when servlet called via Ajax POST

Tags: javascript, java, html, ajax, servlets

I have a login page where I authenticate the user via `firebase` and send the request to a servlet. When I hit the `submit` button with correct authentications, the firebase authentication works, servlet get called but in browser I see see an error.

First of all, this is my javascript code

```
function toggleSignIn() {
    if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
        alert('existing user');
        firebase.auth().signOut();
    } else {
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        var password = document.getElementById('password').value;

        if (email.length < 4) {
            alert('Please enter an email address.');
            return;
        }

        if (password.length < 4) {
            alert('Please enter a password.');
            return;
        }

        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function (firebaseUser) {
            var email = firebase.auth().currentUser.email;
            const options = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'LoginValidator',
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                },
                body: `email=${email}`
            }
            url = 'LoginValidator'
            fetch(url, options)
                .then(response = > response.json())
                .then(data = > console.log(data))
                .catch(e = > console.error(e))
        }).catch(function (error) {
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
                alert('Wrong password.');
            } else {
                alert(errorMessage);
            }
            console.log(error);
            document.getElementById('quickstart-sign-in').disabled = false;
        });
    }
    document.getElementById('quickstart-sign-in').disabled = true;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="login-box" class="col-md-12">

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control login-input" placeholder="username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control login-input" type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password">
        <i id="open" class="fa fa-eye fa-2x"></i>
        <i id="closed" class="fa fa-eye-slash fa-2x"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" id="quickstart-sign-in" name="quickstart-sign-in"
               class="form-control btn btn-info btn-md login-bt" value="Login" onclick="toggleSignIn()">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-center forgot">
        <a href="#">Forgot username</a> / <a href="#">password?</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Below is my servlet

**LoginValidator.java**

```
public class LoginValidator extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        System.out.println("Printing email: "+email);

        try {

            System.out.println("inside try");

            User user = new User();
            UserRight userRight = new UserRight();

            GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
            gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateTypeDeserializer());
            Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BaseURLs.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();

            //Get user
            RestEndPointsInterface endPoint = retrofit.create(RestEndPointsInterface.class);
            Call<User> call = endPoint.getUserByEmail(email);
            user = call.execute().body();

            System.out.println(user.getName());

            //Get user rights
            Call<UserRight> userRightCall = endPoint.getUserRightByID(user.getUserRights().getIduserRight());
            userRight = userRightCall.execute().body();

            System.out.println(userRight.getUserRight());

            if(userRight.getUserRight().equals("admin"))
            {
                response.getWriter().write("{url:LoadSellPendingApprovals}");
            }
            else
            {
                response.getWriter().write("{url:index.html}");
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

The `LoginValidator` calls **LoadSellPendingApprovals**, below is its code

```
public class LoadSellPendingApprovals extends HttpServlet {


    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        List<ProductSellAdvertisement> categoryList = new ArrayList<ProductSellAdvertisement>();

        try {

            System.out.println("INSIDE LoadSellPendingApprovals");

            GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
            gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateTypeDeserializer());
            Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BaseURLs.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();

            RestEndPointsInterface endPoint = retrofit.create(RestEndPointsInterface.class);
            Call<List<ProductSellAdvertisement>> call = endPoint.getAllPendingApprovals();
            categoryList = call.execute().body();

            for (int i = 0; i < categoryList.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(categoryList.get(i).getProduct().getProductName());
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/product-sell-pending-approvals.jsp");
            request.setAttribute("approvalList", categoryList);
            requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }


    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

This is the error I get

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at (index):71
```

[image]

The line being pointed in my javascript code is this - `.then(response => response.json())`

The expected behavior is this

1. User enter credentials
2. Authenticate the credentials with `firebase` javascript api
3. If credentials are correct send them to the `LoginValidator` servlet where it will further check user`s authenticity.
4. Then the `LoginValidator` send the request to `LoadSellPendingApprovals` where it will execute the following code

   RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/product-sell-pending-approvals.jsp");
               request.setAttribute("approvalList", categoryList);
               requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);

In addition to the error I get, I never get forwarded to the JSP page as well. How can I fix this problem?

**I am coming from java and mobile background, have no much clue on Javascript technology. Therefor appreciate detailed clear answers.**

Comment: One note about your question. It increases the likelihood of someone answering your question when you format your code properly. Remove unnecessary comments and code.

Comment: Are you sure `url = 'LoginValidator'` is the right URL to `fetch()`?

Comment: @Jens: Well, what I need to do is this. The HTML file will send the data to `LoginValidator` and `LoginValidator` will send the data to `LoadSellPendingApprovals`. Then `LoadSellPendingApprovals` will send data to `product-sell-pending-approvals.jsp`.

Comment: @Jens: I have posted the `LoadSellPendingApprovals` servlet as well

Comment: Usually URLs look like `http://somedomain/<path-to-servlet>` and not the name of the servlet you want to call.

Comment: @Jens: hmm... Well that works for all other servlets, even the `LoginValidator` get called. I don't mind whether my JS code need to be fully replaced, I just want to do the `firebase` validation and send the request to a servlet and load some UI. Therefor I am open for options. I read in some other posts that this behavior is normal for `Ajax POST` requests and some additional steps need to be taken.  have done that (like printing a `response` in `LoginValidator` but still stuck ) :(

Comment: you are missing semicolon after `url = 'LoginValidator'`

Comment: @sachinrai: Thanks, fix that but the issue remains

Answer (score 0):

Your error indicates that the result "body" does not contain JSON but HTML:

> Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

JSON would look like this:

```
{ key: value }
```

HTML looks like this:

```
<html>....</html>
```

As the error states, the first `<` (position 0) is the "unexpected token". What ever is reading the body was expecting a `{`.

One reason for this might be that the request you are sending is redirected to a login page and therefore you get HTML instead of the expected JSON. Or you get an error page which you are trying to pass to your JSON parser.

Unfortunately, with this little information it is hard to tell. You should debug your code and check the response you are getting.

Comment: Thank you Jens. What more information you require please? I can post them here.

Comment: @PeakGen What is in your `response`? Use your browser Javascript debugger to set a breakpoint and inspect `response`.

Comment: I have posted my servlet, please check the updated answer. I am using `response.getWriter().write("{url:LoadSellPendingApprovals}");` in servlet

Comment: @PeakGen Maybe change `response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");` to `response.setContentType("application/json");`. That would be a start. Since you want to send back JSON and not HTML.

Comment: Still the same scenario

Comment: I have posted the picture of browser console too. Well at the bottom line, I really don't mind whether my javascript code is replaced with some other code, so I am open for suggestions. I just need to get the validation done and get user some UI.